# Problems implementing firebase multiple build types

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I spend the last 3 days trying to separate my production environment from my development environment, i followed this post: [Organizing your Firebase-enabled Android app builds](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html)

**Goal**

I have an app that has google services (login), and I want to implement firebase analytics

**What i did so far**

I imported my project from google to firebase, and i created a new app inside the firebase with package id of `my.package.name.debug`

I'm signing both versions with the same key

Both have the same certs in the firebase console

The json file contains both package names

Gradle

```
debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
```

This fails to compile in debug, if I remove the `applicationIdSuffix` works fine for both release and debug, otherwise this file `R.xml.global_tracker` cannot be found

Comment: `The google-services.json file for my.package.name == my.package.name.debug` What does this mean?

Comment: what i am trying to say is, there is a button to download the json file for `my.package.name` and `my.package.name.debug` they are both equal, the json file contains both package names but for some reason, i can only compile if i remove the `.debug` sufix or choose release

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more specific about the relevant parts of the error message log that you see when you do the build at the command line?